# The getter 'value' was called on null. Receiver: null _listenForPermissionStatus() permission_handler Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions

The below code from https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/example throws an error:
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value)

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_listenForPermissionStatus();
}

void _listenForPermissionStatus() async {
final status = await _permission.status;
setState(() => _permissionStatus = status);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Make sure that _permission is not null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)